# Locating required service to restart

Tags: php, centos7

So my Centos 7 server had  several php.ini files and i managed to locate the one my website using through the command

```
php -i |grep "php.ini"
```

And edited it, But now im lost trying to know the service path that i should restart to start seeing the changes.
Please your insight would help a lot.

ps still I'm progressing my work normally my file path is /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.ini and I edit it via vim then save it and then... I restart the whole server :) `shutdown -r now` which is an overkill but it is what I must do currently until I know the service that I should restart.

Thanks

Comment: How did you install PHP?

Comment: thanks for viewing my question, I'm still learning how to administer Linux so at the time of installation I had to hire someone to install php for me ,,, and I believe he installed several php versions because I found several php.ini files